# тач меню на гибридном устройстве

Tags: javascript, jquery

Описание: 
Есть двухуровненвое меню.
 1. На десктопе при наведении на пункт меню, открывается второй уровень. При клике на пункт меню идёт переход на страницу.
 2. На тач-устройстве: одиночный тап - открывается/закрывается меню, двойной тап - переход на страницу.

Для проверки тач-устройство или нет использовал

`if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) { code }else{ code }`

И прицепил hammer.js для событий tap (навешивается класс) и doubletap (осуществляется переход).

Вопрос: Как осуществить одновременную корректную работу на гибридных устройствах? 
Чтобы на гибриде при работе с мышью отрабатывал ховер, но при этом корректно работал и вариант с тач-падом.